# set custom labels for activity name in Google Analytics

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

i use Google Analytics for monitor my users in my Android app. Now i want to set label's for each activity in google analytics. Just for better understanding i don't want see Activity Class name, instead see my custom label's. how i can do this?

Comment: Have you tried solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in onCreate:

```
// Get tracker.
Tracker t = ((MyApplicationClass)
getActivity().getApplication()).getTracker(MyApplicationClass.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

// Set screen name. Where path is a String representing the screen name.
t.setScreenName("YOUR_CUSTOM_LABLE_FOR_THIS_SCREEN");

// Send a screen view.
t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
```

Answer (score 1):

Initialize variable:

```
private Tracker tracker;
```

onCreate()

```
tracker = ((GlobalClass) getApplication()).getTracker(GlobalClass.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
tracker.setScreenName("Add_your_own_lable");
tracker.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also configure the activity names with XML tracker configuration file.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/#analytics-xml

For example if you like to name "com.example.app.MainActivity" activity as "Home Screen" you can add:

```
<screenName name="com.example.app.MainActivity">
   Home Screen
</screenName>
```

to the configuration file. When creating the tracker, make sure you are using the XML configuration instead of hardcoded trackerId.